# Angularjs minlength not valid even with required length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I am getting error when submitting form.

[image]

I noticed that the when I put required length for minlength it will show successful but in the below there is $error which indicates that the problem is minlength.

So the structure is the there is fo-address.html which is the form.
The fo-address.js is a directive that puts values to the form.
Then in the form there is jn-phone-number which is input that gets information from the form.

I tried debugging this and noticed problem only happens on the minlength but not maxlength, am not sure why this is throwing as not valid.
Any helps or tips would be appreciated. Let me know if extra information is needed.  Thanks.

Part of the form fo-address.html

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
    <label cms-translation="phone" cms-state="checkout">Phone</label>
    <div jn-phone-number="model.shippingAddress.phone" input-type="number" ng-model="model.shippingAddress.phone" input-name="phone" minlength="phoneMin" maxlength="phoneMax" form="shippingForm" required="true" submitted="submitted" country="model.countryCode"></div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
function ($state, localeService, urlHelper, checkoutService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: fo-address.html,
        link: function ($scope, el, attrs) {
                $scope.locale = localeService.getCurrentLocale();
                $scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
                $scope.noDash = (/-\s/g, "");
                $scope.default = true;
                $scope.asia = false;
                $scope.indo = false;
                $scope.hk = false;
                $scope.tw = false;
                $scope.zipMin;
                $scope.zipMax;
                $scope.phoneMin;
                $scope.phoneMax;
                if ($scope.locale == "en-HK" || $scope.locale == "zh-HK" || $scope.locale == "en-TW" || $scope.locale == "zh-TW" || $scope.locale == "en-ID" || $scope.locale == "id-ID") {
                    $scope.asia = true;
                    $scope.default = false;
                    if ($scope.locale == "en-ID" || $scope.locale == "id-ID") {
                        $scope.indo = true;
                        $scope.phoneMin = 10;
                        $scope.phoneMax = 15;
                    }
                    else if ($scope.locale == "en-TW" || $scope.locale == "zh-TW") {
                        $scope.tw = true;
                        $scope.phoneMin = 10;
                        $scope.phoneMax = 15;
                        $scope.zipMin = 6;
                        $scope.zipMax = 6;
                    }
                    else if ($scope.locale == "en-HK" || $scope.locale == "zh-HK") {
                        $scope.hk = true;
                        $scope.phoneMax = 8;
                        $scope.phoneMax = 8;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $scope.default = true;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

jnPhoneNumber Validation

```
'use strict';
define(['../jn-module'],
    function (module) {
        module.directive('jnPhoneNumber', [
            function () {
                return {
                    template: '<input type="{{inputType}}" name="{{inputName}}" class="form-control" ng-model="jnPhoneNumber" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-required="required" minlength="{{minlength}}" maxlength="{{maxlength}}"/><span jn-validation="formNameAndInput" form-submitted="submitted"></span>',
                restrict: 'AE',
                require: '^ngModel',
                scope: {
                    country: '=country',
                    jnPhoneNumber: '=',
                    inputName: '@',
                    form: '=',
                    submitted: '=',
                    required: '=',
                    minlength: '=',
                    maxlength: '=',
                    inputType: '@'

                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    scope.formNameAndInput = scope.form[scope.inputName];
                    if(!scope.maxlength) {
                        scope.maxlength = 20;
                    }
                    if(!scope.minlength) {
                        scope.minlength = 10;
                    }
                    if(!scope.inputType) {
                        scope.inputType = 'text';
                    }
                    switch (scope.country) {
                    case 'US':
                        scope.placeholder = '(555) 555-5555';
                        break;
                    default:
                        scope.placeholder = '';
                    }

                    scope.$watch('jnPhoneNumber', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        scope.setValue(newValue);
                    });

                    scope.setValue = function (value) {
                        if(scope.placeholder !== ''){
                            if (value) {
                                var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
                                value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
                            }
                            ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                        }
                    };
                }
```

Comment: can you provide a plunkar?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WKeguMPPGFc7yEAFDVMz?p=info